# project name in gradle must be a directory?

Tags: gradle

Is it mandatory to have a directory with same name as project in gradle ? My code is like this:

.

```
|-- build.gradle
`-- suites
    `-- lrgabc.gradle

1 directory, 2 files
```

content of suites/lrgabc.gradle

```
$ cat suites/lrgabc.gradle 
project(':lrgabc') {
    task block1 << {
        println "Hello from lrgabc.block1"
    }
}
```

Content of build.gradle

```
apply from: 'suites/lrgabc.gradle'
```

When I run, gradle -q :lrgabc:block1 I get

```
* Where:
Script '/home/skgupta/gradle-examples/multiproject/suites/lrgabc.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Project with path ':lrgabc' could not be found in root project 'multiproject'.
```

Is it mandatory to have 'lrgabc' as a directory under 'multiproject' ?

What I'm trying is under one single project, create multiple test suites using gradle. Each test suite is one gradle file, where each task in that gradle represent one test [These are non java tests, like perl, python..etc]

How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each subproject in a multi-project Gradle build needs to have a separate project directory. However, directory names do not have to correspond to project names (this is configurable in `settings.gradle`).

Answer (score 1):

1. You really want to take a look at the documentation for multi-project builds - http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html There are also samples in Gradle distribution that can help you.
2. You don't need to create new projects to create more test tasks. You can have these tests in one project. It is quite common to define multiple test suite like unit and functional tests this way. http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/08/22/gradle-test-organization/ shows a possible implementation.